# In Python, what would be a clear, efficient way to count things in regions?

Tags: python, count, range, histogram, binning

I am looping over objects called events. Each event has a particular object in it. I am calculating the fraction of objects that have a particular characteristic. Imagine the approach as being something like the following:

```
for event in events:
    countCars =+ 1
    if event.car.isBlue() is True:
        countCarsBlue =+ 1

print("fraction of cars that are blue: {fraction}".format(
    fraction = countCarsBlue / countCars))
```

Now, imagine that I want to calculate the fraction of objects that have the particular characteristic *in regions of another of the object's characteristics*. So, in my example, I am counting the fraction of cars that are blue. Now, I want to calculate the fraction of cars that are blue in the range of car lengths from 0 m to 1 m, the fraction of cars that are blue in the range of car lengths from 1 m to 2 m, from 2 m to 3 m and from 3 m to 4 m and so on.

Given that I am dealing with a lot of statistics and many more bins than the 4 bins of my simple example, what would be a good way to structure the code for this type of calculation, assuming a constant bin width?

(Would there be a sensible way to do this for *variable* bin widths?)

Comment: You could append to a pandas DataFrame (essentially a table) with columns for each of the characteristics of the events.  So with each iteration of the for loop, you would gather all of the characteristics of a car into one list, then you would append to the DataFrame.  Then you could easily query the DataFrame for complex conditions.  This may not be efficient, but it is easy to query.

Comment: Minor remark, to test the the *truthiness* of a variable, don't compare it to a boolean with `is True`, just add it to the `if` statement. See [here](https://pedantic-python.readme.io/docs/truth-value-testing) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some code to recreate your example:

```
import random

class Event(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.car = None

class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, isBlue, length):
        self._isBlue = isBlue
        self._length = length

    def isBlue(self):
        return self._isBlue

    def length(self):
        return self._length

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} car of {} m long.'.format('blue' if self.isBlue() else 'non-blue ', self.length())
```

OK, now I randomly create ten `car`objects and add them to an `event`:

```
totalNumberOfCars = 10
events = []
for _ in range(totalNumberOfCars):
    car = Car(random.choice([True, False]), random.randrange(5, 40)/10.)
    print car
    event = Event()
    event.car = car
    events.append(event)
```

For me, the output was as follows (your output can of course be different):

```
blue car of 0.5 m long.
non-blue  car of 2.3 m long.
non-blue  car of 3.8 m long.
blue car of 2.1 m long.
non-blue  car of 0.6 m long.
blue car of 0.8 m long.
blue car of 0.5 m long.
blue car of 2.3 m long.
blue car of 3.3 m long.
blue car of 2.1 m long.
```

Now, if we want to count our events by region, you could do it as follows:

```
allBlueCars = sum(1 for event in events if event.car.isBlue())
print "Number of blue cars: {}".format(allBlueCars)

maxCarLen = 4
for region in zip(range(maxCarLen ), range(1, maxCarLen +1)):
    minlen, maxlen = region
    print "Cars between {} and {} m that are blue:".format(minlen, maxlen)
    blueCarsInRegion = [str(event.car) for event in events if event.car.isBlue() and minlen <= event.car.length() < maxlen]
    if blueCarsInRegion:
        print '\n'.join(['\t{}'.format(car) for car in blueCarsInRegion])
    else:
        print 'no blue cars in this region'
    fraction = float(len(blueCarsInRegion)) / allBlueCars
    print "fraction of cars that are blue and between {} and {} m long: {}".format(minlen, maxlen, fraction)
    print
```

For the above sample data, that would print:

```
Number of blue cars: 7
Cars between 0 and 1 m that are blue:
    blue car of 0.5 m long.
    blue car of 0.8 m long.
    blue car of 0.5 m long.
fraction of cars that are blue and between 0 and 1 m long: 0.428571428571

Cars between 1 and 2 m that are blue:
no blue cars in this region
fraction of cars that are blue and between 1 and 2 m long: 0.0

Cars between 2 and 3 m that are blue:
    blue car of 2.1 m long.
    blue car of 2.3 m long.
    blue car of 2.1 m long.
fraction of cars that are blue and between 2 and 3 m long: 0.428571428571

Cars between 3 and 4 m that are blue:
    blue car of 3.3 m long.
fraction of cars that are blue and between 3 and 4 m long: 0.142857142857
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with Python 3.4+, enums would actually be pretty useful for this. Here's a couple of examples of what you could do:

```
import random
from enum import Enum
from collections import namedtuple


class Color(Enum):
    blue = 'blue'
    red = 'red'
    green = 'green'

Car = namedtuple('Car', ('color', 'length'))

cars = [Car(Color.blue, 10),
        Car(Color.blue, 3),
        Car(Color.blue, 9),
        Car(Color.red, 9),
        Car(Color.red, 7),
        Car(Color.red, 8),
        Car(Color.green, 3),
        Car(Color.green, 7),
        Car(Color.green, 2),
        Car(Color.green, 8),
        ]

print('# of blue cars:', sum(1 for car in cars if car.color == Color.blue))
print('# of cars with length between 3 and 7:',
      sum(1 for car in cars if 3 <= car.length <= 7))

random_color = random.choice(tuple(Color))
lower_limit = random.randint(1,10)
upper_limit = random.randint(lower_limit,10)
print('# of {} cars with length {} to {} (inclusive):'.format(random_color.name,
                                                              lower_limit,
                                                              upper_limit),
      sum(1 for car in cars if car.color == random_color
                            and lower_limit <= car.length <= upper_limit))

important_colors = (Color.blue, Color.green)
important_lengths = (1,2,3,5,7)

print('Number of cars that match some contrived criteria:',
      sum(1 for car in cars if car.color in important_colors
                            and car.length in important_lengths))
```

If you're talking about a continuous range, `lower < value < upper` is a great way to check. If you have discrete values (like colors) you can create a collection of the interesting colors and check for membership in that collection. Also note that you can easily use variable bin sizes.

You could also use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) if you're interested in more than simple counting. Do note that if your items are reference objects that changing something in one collection will change it in the other:

```
In [15]: class Simple:
   ....:     def __init__(self, name):
   ....:         self.name = name
   ....:     def __repr__(self):
   ....:         return 'Simple(name={!r})'.format(self.name)
   ....:

In [16]: values = [Simple('one'), Simple('two'), Simple('three')]

In [17]: one = (values[0], values[-1])

In [18]: two = tuple(values[:2])

In [19]: one
Out[19]: (Simple(name='one'), Simple(name='three'))

In [20]: two
Out[20]: (Simple(name='one'), Simple(name='two'))

In [21]: one[0].name = '**changed**'

In [22]: one
Out[22]: (Simple(name='**changed**'), Simple(name='three'))

In [23]: two
Out[23]: (Simple(name='**changed**'), Simple(name='two'))
```

Comment: The enum package can also be easily installed in other versions of Python, so 3.4+ isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: @eqzx Cool, I wasn't aware of that. I'm one of the fortunate ones that gets to work in Python3, so I don't get as much exposure to the challenges that the rest of the world faces ;)